# Edit XML value in Beanshell using Java?

Tags: java, javascript, xml, jmeter, beanshell

I have the following request in JMeter in XML which looks as follows:

```
<gml:lowerCorner>13.84 6.3677</gml:lowerCorner>
<gml:upperCorner>64.9404 17.8612</gml:upperCorner>
```

How do I edit these values so that each time they are randomly generated? I am hoping to achieve this in Java but also considering Javascript. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using [JMeter Functions](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/64307-using-jmeter-functions-part-ii) instead. It looks like that [_*Random()*](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__Random) or [_RandomString()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__RandomString) could be a good choice.

Something like

```
<gml:lowerCorner>${__Random(0,99,)}.${__Random(0,99,)} ${__Random(0,9,)}.${__Random(1111,9999,)}</gml:lowerCorner>
```

Should do the trick for you.

It isn't recommended to use Beanshell for heavy scripting. For something once-only or very light like reading configuration file, appending something to the log, etc. it's fine, but several calls to obtain a random number can have negative impact on your test performance. If you need to go down to Java code I'd suggest using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) (or Pre Processor) and Groovy as language as it provides performance comparative to native Java code.

Comment: Where does this go exactly?

Comment: And if I wanted to go the JSR223 route how would I go about this?

Comment: You can use JMeter Functions anywhere, i.e. right in request body. For JSR223 - you need to download groovy-all.jar and drop it to /lib folder of your JMeter installation. After that all you need is to set `groovy` language for JSR223 sampler or pre-processor and either provide path to file or inline the script into "script" input. In second case make sure that you're using `Compilation cache key` and it's unique for all JSR223 samplers being used. After calculation of random numbers via groovy script you can store them to JMeter Variables (see `vars` pre-defined element) and reuse in sampler